# How to draw connecting lines in plain color?

Tags: shaders, opengl-es2, fragment-shader

Since there is no option for flat shading in OpenGL ES2, is there a workaround to disable the color interpolation when different color is being passed to each of the vertices?

**Update:**
I'm working with OpengGL ES 2.0 in android. I'm given with these vertices which I used to draw shapes by connecting them with lines. Now I need to change color of each of these lines individually. I tried passing a color matrix for each vertex through vertex shader to fragment shader but the color gets interpolated (which actually makes sense, since I'm giving different color to two vertices). I did some googling about that and found out glSmoothShader cannot be disabled in OpengGL ES.

Is there a way to color those lines without the colors getting interpolated?

Or is there a way to use multiple triangles to draw a line between two vertices that way i can flat color each of those triangles.

Comment: Not really. What solved the problem in that question is using flat shading.. which isn't available in OpengGL ES.

Comment: See if you can state that explicitly in the question, explaining how gles2.0 is different

Comment: See if you can not comment without even understanding the context. I have clearly mentioned OpenGL ES in the question. Why even bother commenting if you don't even know the difference between ES and normal OpenGL.

Comment: You could try placing a bounty on the question, asking for an additional answer, but I agree that this question is a ***duplicate***.

Comment: The suggested answer is for OpenGL, the question I've asked is about OpenGL ES. How on earth is that duplicate? They are totally different things.

Comment: What about the question? You guys don't look at the question either to call it a duplicate? The question asked there is, "I would like for the color between my vertices to not be rendered as a gradient, but as a hard break. Is there any way to accomplish this in OpenGL/GLSL?" clearly the guy is asking about OpenGL/GLSL not about OpenGL ES they are two different things.

Comment: On a side note, as it stands, the question is quite broad. There's no context, no desired behavior. Suggestions to improve: **1.** Explain why linked "possible duplicate" question AND answers to it (which involve solutions suitable for GLES2) do not work for you, what are the key differences and incompatibilities. **2.** State the problem you are trying to solve. It is possible that it can be solved from different sides altogether. **3.** State what do you want to see instead, when color interpolation is "disabled" - solid color, stepped transitions, something else? *Help us to help you!*

Comment: I updated the question. I hope its understandable now. My apologies for being rude earlier. @Kromster

Comment: The question is much better now. Please see if you can post a screenshot illustrating the problem. It looks like there are several possible solutions if you re-formulate the questions into "How to draw connecting lines in plain color?", but without a screenshot it's hard to tell. *Mandatory side note: "The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem. That is, you are trying to solve problem X , and you think solution Y would work, but instead of asking about X when you run into trouble, you ask about Y."*

Comment: Do I need to post screenshots? The problem I'm facing is when i try to draw a line and pass two vertices, I'm also required to pass different color to each of those vertices which is resulting in the color being interpolated. What I want to get is a flat color. I'm told that FLAT SHADING in OpenGL solves that issues by applying color of the first vertex to the line. But since that method is not available for GLES I've reached a dead end. @Kromster

Comment: If you can not change your vertex generation logic or pipeline before it hits the GPU memory, there is no hope.

Comment: *"Do I need to post screenshots?"* - Only if you want better help, that is ;-)

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL ES does not support the `flat` keyword that is designed for that. There is currently no way to stop interpolating the fragments other than change your vertices to just use the same values on each vertex. That doesn't really stop the interpolation, but does achieve what you want for the end result.

You are not specifying how you are rendering your lines. If you are rendering them as GL_LINES then just apply the same color value on each line vertex. If you are using GL_LINESTRIP or GL_LINELOOP and are stuck with that, just add additional vertex to where you want the color gradient not happen.

Comment: I'm using GL_LINES. And applying same color value to vertices works. But the problem is the color on other lines connected to that vertex gets interpolated which isn't a desired behavior here.

Comment: Then you need to generate different vertex with different color on the same spot as the previous vertex is on.

Comment: I've gotten that solution before. But calculating indices on run-time would be an even greater pain then it already is.

Comment: Can't you precompute them then? Do you need them to be dynamic?

Comment: No I can't since the app gets the drawing data from server in real time as xml file.

Comment: That's what you have to do then. You need to generate the new indices in real time.

Comment: Is there a reason why "flat" isn't supported in GLES?

Comment: I'm sure there is. I just don't know why. It's been the decision of [OpenGL ARB](https://www.opengl.org/archives/about/arb/).

Comment: GLES was supposed to be modern lite-weight GL for mobiles. Many features were cut to make it lighter.